# ASP.NET AJAX PUT Method not allowed and Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

When I send ajax request to my `text.aspx` file then I've got error `405 (Method not allowed)` but when I add this to my `web.config` then I have `401 (Unauthorized)`

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> <!-- ADD THIS -->
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

below my test.aspx.cs file and test.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page {

    public string method;
    public int age = 24;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        method = Request.ServerVariables["request_method"];
        if(method=="PUT") {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write("PUTEM JE");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" inherits="Test" %>
<body>
  <script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    xhr.open('put', '/moja/test.aspx', true);
    xhr.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

also add this line to your config after the modules:

```
<handlers>
   <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i found a solution! :)
[image]

We can just add `PUT, DELETE` in Request Restrictions within *.aspx paths

But it don't work without this in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
            <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```